# what is location of monogo shell path?

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am using docker.I pull mongoDB image .then my db is connected successfully.
Now I want to know where is my monogo shell location ?? I am using webstrom or intellij I want to write path of mongo shell here

[image]

my docker congiguration
Environment properties
[image] 
Port binding

[image]

**could you please tell me Mongo shell path ?**

Comment: nothing happened..I installed mongoDB through docker

Comment: If you installed MongoDB in a Docker container, the `mongo` shell and other command-line binaries will also be in the container. From your screenshots it looks like the host environment where you are running IDEs is macOS; the binaries in the Docker container will be for Linux. You need to [install MongoDB Community Edition for macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-community-edition) in order to get the relevant `mongo` shell binary to use in your macOS IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Bash into your container and searched with  "which" command ?

$ which mongo

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to have answer..

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-mongodb-work-in-docker-how-to-connect-with-mongodb/44763

Or try using this Jet brains plugin

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7724-docker-integration

Comment: Did you try the first method ?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you run the docker, for example, if you run like

```
docker run -d --name mongocontainer -p 27017:27017  mongo
```

you can connect it by

```
mongo --host localhost
```